# MatLab: optional turn on legend

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, legend

I'm trying to write the code to set up the figures and legend to look nice. I made code that plotting the figures

```
figure(1)
hold on
plot(x1, y1, 'DisplayName', name1)
plot(x2, y2, 'DisplayName', name2)
plot(x3, y3, 'DisplayName', name3)
```

Now, I need another script, that should turn the legend on only if `name1` `name2` and `name3` in original figure were actually set to some non-default value i.e. not `''`, otherwise I don't need a legend at all.

```
function optionallegend(figure)
if ????
     legend('show');
end
```

Can I do that?

Comment: That's default value i.e. I didn't set up any specific name for it. I'll clarify it in the main post as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html) to locate all plot objects within your current axes that have the `DisplayName` property and have defined it to be something other than `''`. `findobj` returns an array of handles which can then be passed to `legend`. If no plots meet that criteria, then no legend will be shown.

```
plots = findobj(gca, '-not', 'DisplayName', '', '-property', 'DisplayName');

if ~isempty(plots); legend(plots); end
```

And as an example

```
figure;
hax = axes();
hold(hax, 'on')

plot(rand(5,1), 'DisplayName', 'Plot #1');
plot(rand(5,1))
plot(rand(5,1), 'DisplayName', 'Plot #3');

legend(findobj(hax, '-not', 'DisplayName', '', '-property', 'DisplayName'));
```

[image]

If instead you want to simply plot a legend for only specific plots, you can explicitly store the plot handles and pass those to `legend` directly.

```
hplot1 = plot(rand(5,1), 'DisplayName', 'Plot #1');
hplot2 = plot(rand(5,1), 'DisplayName', 'Plot #2');

legend([hplot1, hplot2])
```

Comment: Can you also skip items in the legend by this method?

Comment: @Alex You can pass any array of handles to `legend()` so you can pass only those you want to plot.

Comment: @Alex I added a little demo at the end showing how to do that

Comment: Actually, even though it's very awesome way of handling the legends (I had this issue before and your way is better than what I found in other topic) it doesn't work exactly in my case, if all of the `DisplayName` are `''`. Matlab still make a legend in this case making it `data1`, `data2` etc.

Comment: @Alex the first example is updated with a check for not plots with display names

Comment: That's just such a great way. I bet I'll use it many times again. Thank you very much.